# Generating Hierarchy using Maps and path variable

Tags: java, database, recursion, hashmap, hierarchy

I've got a family class that pulls data from a postgres database. The class looks like something like this:

```
@Entity
public class Family(){
@Id
private long id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private Long parentId;
private4 String familyPath;
private List<Family> children;

//getters and setters
```

In the database, I have their relation to each other stored as a period-delimited string. So for example, if Bob is the child of Sue, the tree column would look like: "bob.sue". This path is stored as part of the family object in the familyPath variable.

**CLARIFICATION**
familyPath is a path based on unique IDs for each row in the database. So a path may look like "1.2.3" where the last number is the current row. 
"1.2.4" is another potential path. so rows with IDs 3 and 4 are children of 2, etc.

In my code I query the database for all family members in the data, so I have a set of every member of the family in the database. My goal is to generate a set of all family members as a hierarchical structure using this initial, flat set. So, in the end if I call getChildren on Bob, I get a list back containing Sue and any other children.

**My Solution:**

First, I iterate through my list of families, and find what I call the root members -- those at the top level of the family path -- and remove them into a separate list. So now I have a list of top level family members, an a list of everyone else.

Then, for each member in the top level list, I call the following recursive method:

```
private Family familyTree(Family root, List<Family> members) {
    List<Family> children = new ArrayList<>();


    for (Family f : members) {
        if (isChildOf(f, root)) {
            children.add(familyTree(f, resources));
        }
    }
    root.setChildren(children);
    return root;
}


private boolean isChildOf(Family a, Family b) {
    String pCPath = a.getFamilyPath();
    String pPPath = b.getFamilyPath();

    return pCPath.indexOf('.') >= 0
            && pCPath.substring(0, pCPath.lastIndexOf('.')).equals(pPPath);
}
```

and save the output to a list. This generates the desired results.

**My Question**
However, I feel that this recursive method is very expensive (n^2). I'm thinking that there may be a more efficient way to generate this hierarchy using sets, maps and the Family object's familyPath variable, But i keep getting stuck in multiple iterative loops. Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Please add the code of isChildOf

Comment: Added to the recursive function's code block

Comment: I've also added a parentId column to the database, and a corresponding variable to the model. So now each family object has the id of it's parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Option 1 - Single pass

```
private Family familyTree(Family root, List<Family> members) {
    Map<Long, List<Family>> parentMap = new HashMap<>();

    // Assuming root is not contained in members
    root.children  = new ArrayList<>();
    parentMap.put(root.id, root.children);

    // Assign each member to a child list
    for (Family member : members) {

        // Put the family member in the right child list
        Long parentId = member.getParentId();
        List<Family> parentChildren = parentMap.get(parentId);
        if (parentChildren == null) {
            parentChildren = new ArrayList<>();
            parentMap.put(parentId, parentChildren);
        }
        parentChildren.add(member);

        // Get or create the child list of the family member
        List<Family> ownChildren = parentMap.get(member.id);
        if (ownChildren == null) {
            ownChildren = new ArrayList<>();
            parentMap.put(member.id, ownChildren);
        }
        member.children = ownChildren;
    }
    return root;
}

private Long getParentId() {
    // left as an exercise...
}
```

### Option 1.b - Single pass over all members including roots

```
private List<Family> familyTree(List<Family> members) {
    List<Family> roots = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<Long, List<Family>> parentMap = new HashMap<>();

    // Assign each member to a child list
    for (Family member : members) {

        // Put the family member in the right child list
        Long parentId = member.getParentId();
        if (parentId == null) {
            // a root member
            roots.add(member);
        } else {
            // a non-root member
            List<Family> parentChildren = parentMap.get(parentId);
            if (parentChildren == null) {
                parentChildren = new ArrayList<>();
                parentMap.put(parentId, parentChildren);
            }
            parentChildren.add(member);
        }

        // Get or create the child list of the family member
        List<Family> ownChildren = parentMap.get(member.id);
        if (ownChildren == null) {
            ownChildren = new ArrayList<>();
            parentMap.put(member.id, ownChildren);
        }
        member.children = ownChildren;
    }
    return roots;
}
```

## Option 2 - Add a reference to the parent

Your `Family` class should have a `private Family parent` attribute. You will then be able to do a single query per family "level". That is:

1. get all children of Sue
2. get all children of people from (1) and assign them to the proper parent
3. etc.

## Option 3 - Nested Set Model of Hierarchies

The database schema can be modified to retrieve whole sub-trees in a single query. The trick is to give each tree node a "left" and a "right" value. These values establish a range for the "left" and "right" values of a node's children.

Selecting a full tree can then be done like this:

```
SELECT child.id, ...
FROM family AS child, family AS parent
WHERE child.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
    AND parent.id = 111
ORDER BY child.lft;
```

There are many other hierarchical operations which can be done very easily with such a schema. See [this post](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) and *Joe Celko's Trees and Hierarchies in SQL for Smarties* for more information.

Finally, your model only considers a single parent for each family member which seems strange.

Comment: I've added clarification above: the familyPath is by ID, which is unique for each entry in the database. So a familyPath may look something like "1.2.3.4"

Comment: Thank you! You solution is exactly what i was building towards

Comment: we're still looking at n^2 time complexity, right? Because we're looping through each top level family member, and we're looping through each non-top level family member in the familytree method. So if we have a very large list of both, O(n^2)

Comment: Your first implementation was much worse than n^2. Each child iterated through the whole list and its children too etc. I respected the method signature you provided in your question. See my update (1.5) for a single pass method.